# How to save the selected value from picker component

Tags: codenameone

I've using autocompleteTF & picker component to select items. When the user select the item somechanges occur.
But if the user exit the app and open it again the selected value were return to its default value. So how to make the app to remember the previous value when opened again?

Answer (score 0):

See this on saving your application state: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html

Since this is one or two values just store it in preferences dynamically. E.g. use:

```java
String value = Prefrences.get("name", null);
```

`value` would be null if not set.

Similarly when you have a selection just put a value into preferences under the same name.